# How to recover data lost by clean command in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, hard-drive-recovery, partition-recovery

I was trying to install new OS in my HP pavilion 2000 series 6gb ram, 500gb HDD, 2.4GHz i3 3rd Gen processor. At some point I was not able to delete the partition So I googled for it. I got a solution to clean the drive for solve that problem.

I inserted the disc and go to the repairing tool of windows. In command prompt I just entered few commands given below:

```
diskpart
list disk
select disk 0 //my internal HDD
clean
```

I thought the command will remove the bad sectors from the disk and solve the problem. When I processed further to install OS I was just shocked to see my whole drive had been showing free. Now, I dont have any OS in my laptop.

I dont know what to do? I search for this in google. But I got the answers for existing windows drives. like TEST DISK tool.

can anyone tell me what is the solution of this problem?

It would be great help for me If i could get my drives back.

Comment: Is there any reason for downvote?

Comment: you can recover using freeware software lie recuva. but still you can not recover 100% and in sorted order.

Comment: If I install windows again will it be caused problem in recoery?

Comment: for recover your documents and images etc you should partioned your HDD as it was partioned previous and then install windows again and then install recuva or run it. remeber that store the recovered files in any external storage device instead of same drive.

Comment: I had 3 drives before. 1 is for windows and 2 for data. So Do I need to create with same drive letter?

Comment: no its not necessary to create with same letter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you only deleted the partition table. The good news are that you will be able to recover your information.
I'd use [Testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk). You can see a detailed tutorial on recovering partitions here: [TestDisk Step By Step](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step)

Comment: thanx.  yeah I have seen this tool but I need to install this tool first and therefore I will have to install windows in my laptop. If I install windows again will it be cause any problem to recovering again?

Comment: @Exception You can run TestDisk from a [live cd](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Livecd) so you don't need to reinstall windows (at least to recover your partitions).

Comment: @Exception Don't install anything on that drive or you will loose data!. As DavidPostill said, use a LiveCD